# How to added labels into StepAreaChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I try to solve how to added custom labels into StepAreaChart. The similar example can be seen on the picture below. 
Each area should have custom label.
I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

[image: Example]

Comment: Have you tried any of the `org.jfree.chart.annotations`?

Comment: Actually not yet. So let say that if I would use XYShapeAnnotation then I can reach this kind of labels in my stack areas ?

Comment: Yes, but your image looks more like a text, title or drawable annotation

Comment: Also consider an `XYItemLabelGenerator`.