# Setup position of subtitles in XYStepAreaChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I try to organize subtitle for each area in XYStepAreaChart. As example subtitle CN1 should be under the LM and CL1 should be under LM. I have reach the order by CompositeTitle but right now I need to setup right location under the each area.
I try to solve by padding or used EmptyBlock which create space between each subtitle but no luck.

I would appreciate any suggestion or different point of view how can be reached.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mcve]

Comment: An annotation, suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57709906/230513), accepts data coordinates, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56587266/230513); in contrast, a title accepts chart coordinates.